# How do I comment rather than answer?

Tags: discussion, support, comments

Ok, firstly, sorry if this is obvious or is covered somewhere I should have seen.

However, I can't seem to figure out how comment on a question. Looking around the page all I really see is the options to edit or post an answer.

Is it to do with my low rep? I seem to remember me having commented a time or two... But I might just be crazy...

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Congrats!  You now have comment everywhere!  Keep up the good work!

Comment: Only if every lowbie is as astute and discerning as you are. +1

Comment: [I feel like there is a page for this somewhere](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).

Comment: Oh snap, that privileges page was exactly what the doctor ordered. I suppose I didn't look hard enough. But it can be so tempting to ask a question, on a q & a type site.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Welcome to the site, Bob!

Once you earn 50 reputation, you'll be able to post comments on **any** post.

By default, you may post comments on **your own** questions / answers.

See [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment) for more info.